# C, есть ли смысл проверять результат printf(), fclose() и пр

Tags: c

В каких случаях нужно проверять результат этих функций?

Например, где-то глубоко в коде имеются простые:

```
...
printf("Операция началась.\n");
...
printf("Операция закончилась.\n");
...
fclose(f);
```

Есть ли смысл в таких случаях проверять возвращаемое значение?

Например, у меня имеется функция контролируемого обрушения приложения:

```
void crash_run(const char *_str, ...);
```

Например, если **malloc()** в какой-то неудачный момент вернул **NULL**, имеет смысл падать немедленно.

Перед тем, как вызвать **abort()** функция контролируемого обрушения пытается открыть файл лога и занести туда информацию о проблеме.

Проблема, собственно, заключается в том, что если обрабатывать коды возврата всяких там **printf()**, **fclose()** и прочих мелких штук, то 200 строк ясного кода превращаются в тысячи строк рекурсивного хаоса.

Что делать?

Comment: Если Вы пишете программу для курсовой - то нет, не обязательно. Если же пишете управления ядерным реактором или кардиостимулятором, то тут даже вопрос не должен возникать.

Comment: Окей, что делать, если глубоко в коде printf("123"); внезапно вернул <= 0? Какие вообще естb варианты?

Comment: @Максим, проверить, не выводите ли Вы какой-то мусор...))

Comment: Ошибки бывают разные, BUG относительно неправильной строки формата. Проверять это нужно только в режиме отладки. Или консоль вообще недоступна. Проверять нужно только в начале проги.

Comment: Я не видел в документации ничего о том, что printf() может завершиться неудачно только из-за неверной строки формата.

Comment: `fprintf(stdout,"%S");` возвращает -1

Comment: И? Что делать, если printf("123\n"); вернул <= 0?

Comment: По сути система вызовет сигнал аборта раньше чем наступит ваша функция сообщения об ошибке. Если конечно не переопределить или игнорировать сигнал аборт :) но это моветон, мягко говоря. С функцией printf такая же ситуация, если формат строки вами перепутан, упадет все,  например если в литер `%s` попробовать записать `unsigned long long`

Comment: С чего вдруг моя система упадет? Вот я делаю int i = printf("123\n"); После чего в i оказывается записан 0 или -1. Мной ничего не перепутано, просто функция по неведомой причине завершилась плохо. Что вы предлагаете мне делать? Как это обрабатывать?

Comment: Такую ситуацию - никак, это не к чему. Но это первый звонок о том что в самой программе вероятно уже что то не так с распределением и/или корректной очисткой памяти.

Answer (score 4):

Если это курсовая - то ничего или просто упасть.

Если это кардиостимулятор, то что там делает printf глубоко? Логирует? А нужно ли?

Если это космическая ракета - там тоже можно и упасть:) Главное что бы людей на борту не было.

Если это реактор, то там обычно просчитываются такие варианты и обкладывают и if, и ещё много чем с откатыванием состояния приложения в "устойчивое положение".

Comment: Можно начать внедрять `setjmp/ longjmp` но в результате получиться аналог stl :)

Comment: Я боюсь, что в результате получится не аналог stl, а рак мозга)

Answer (score 3):

Если уж на то пошло, то вообще в своей задаче не должно быть никаких принтов. Своя задача (то, что сейчас называют по-умному бизнес-логика) должна быть оформлена как функция и должна принимать и возвращать в случае языка Си параметры. В случае языка С++ можно еще выбрасывать исключения. Ошибки нужно оформлять как некую структуру, которая заполняется в процессе работы задачи.

А вот все принты надо выносить в отдельную "задачу печати" в отдельный тред на уровне операционки, который ждет семафора из своей задачи и по семафору печатает то, что ему положено печатать.

При такой организации вычислительного процесса в своей задачи не надо проверять код возврата принтов, потому что принтов в своей задаче просто нет.

В "задаче печати" можно и проверить код возврата принтов. Конечно, если вся система действительно управляет ядерным реактором. И в случае неправильного кода возврата принта надо выдавать команду на останов реактора.

Comment: *А вот все принты надо выносить в отдельную "задачу печати" в отдельный тред на уровне операционки* - этот отдельный тред называется *syslog*. Не надо изобретать деревянных велосипедов! Кроме того, огромное (!!!) преимущество сислога заключается в том, что он остаётся(!) после закрытия сессии упавшей задачи. А в случае, если Ваш шеф даёт Вам задание разобраться с ошибкой, которая произошла вчера на компе в штате Алабама, то начинаешь ненавидеть тех "программистов", которые для выдачи сообщений об ошибке используют *printf()*.

Comment: *не надо проверять код возврата принтов* - действительно, не надо. Но по другой причине. Если я печатаю **константу**, то не может быть такой ситуации, когда первый раз константа напечаталась, а второй раз - нет. Проверять тут нечего. Если же печатаем **переменную**, то ошибка может возникнуть только в том случае, если переменная содержит недопустимое значение. Но это надо проверять не при печати, а там, где идёт присвоение. Ситуацию с ошибочным кодом форматирования я не рассматриваю, т.к. это должно быть выявлено на этапе тестирования и в дальнейшем возникнуть не может.

Comment: @Sergey Еще может быть выход за пределы адресного пространства при печати элемента массива. Еще может быть ошибочный код форматирования, но по этой ветке тесты не прошли.

Comment: *в случае неправильного кода возврата принта надо выдавать команду на останов реактора.* - ирония тут абсолютно неуместна. Напомню широко известный пример, когда совместный проект NASA/ESA запуска станции к Венере накрылся медным тазом  из-за того, что в Европе высоту измеряли в метрах, а в США - в футах. Проще говоря, на вход *printf()* подавались недопустимые значения. В случае с атомным реактором всё может кончиться значительно хуже...

Comment: *"Еще может быть"* - оба эти случая я упомянул. 1) Надо проверять ПРИСВОЕНИЕ а не печать. 2) При тестировании должно быть полное покрытие.

Comment: @Sergey [При тестировании должно быть полное покрытие] Тогда время тестирования стремится к бесконечности.

Comment: Это не совсем так. Если программу изобразить в виде блоксхемы на листе бумаги, то этот лист будет иметь **конечную**  площадь. Другое дело, что по стрелочкам этой блоксхемы можно ходить бесконечно. Так что качество тестирования определяется разработчиком теста. И никакие автоматизировыанные системы тестирования здесь не помогут.

Comment: @Sergey [Надо проверять ПРИСВОЕНИЕ] Проверять ВСЕ присвоения в программе это еще более затратно, чем проверять коды возврата принтов. Кроме того, выход за границы адресного пространства вызовет ошибку не принта а операционки.

Comment: @Sergey [этот лист будет иметь конечную площадь] Площадь то конечная, а количество комбинаций переменных очень большое и перебрать все возможные комбинации данных не получится.

Comment: Мы погрузились в мутные глубины теории программирования:-) Вопрос про не инициализированные и неправильно инициализированные переменные очень стар. Очень любопытное решение предлагается в языке Rust. Выход за границы индексов тоже ловится во многих языках программирования.  Всё это не проблемы... Проблема между баранкой и сиденьем :-)

Comment: У человека конкретный вопрос - когда ему проверять код возврата принта и надо ли это делать. И что делать, если принт вернул код ошибки. Ну так вот, подход в том, что задача печати должна быть сделана как отдельный тред или даже процесс отдельно от своей задачи.